# Why is The Following equality true? (limit of a sum and integrals)

Tags: analysis

I saw the following equality:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[ \frac{1}{(1+\frac{k}{n})^3}\right]\dfrac{1}{n} = \int\limits_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{(1+x)^3}dx$$

Why don't we divide the integral by n?

Comment: The expression on the left is the limit of the right Riemann sum (equal subintervals) of  the integrand on the right hand side over the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#/media/File:Riemann_sum_convergence.png

Comment: I don't see an explicit formula on wikipedia that tells me that the expression on the left is a right riemann sum

Comment: Yeah you have to *find* the function $f$... Sure you cannot do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) dx \approx \sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{a_{k-1}}^{a_k}f(x)dx \approx \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(a_k)(a_k-a_{k-1}),$$
using the right Riemman sum. In your case, use $a_k=\frac{k}{n}$ and $f(x)=(1+x)^{-3}$. Then take the limit $n\to\infty$.

The $\frac{1}{n}$ term on the LHS in your expression is, precisely, the length of each subinterval: $a_k-a_{k-1}$.